# Android Facebook login always ask for user after logout

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am implementing a Facebook login with Facebook SDK on Android.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

I'm logging in with the user as

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    ..
}
```

And for log out, I use my own log out button and log out the user programmatically:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

My question is:

After log out, when I click on `Continue with Facebook`, the previous user information pops up to `Continue as XY`. I don't want this. I want to ask for email and password again, every time, if somebody wants to log in after log out. How can I do this?

Comment: Still looking for answer.. let me know how you did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i found the solution. I changed the login behavior for the FB login button, for this i used:

```
    loginButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);
```

So every time it pops up the WEB view for login button.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ask for email, password again every time if somebody wants
>   to log in after log out.

try this in your `onCreate()`

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()); //add this method
```

Now in `updateWithToken()` method `logout` the user from previous session

```
private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

    if (currentAccessToken != null) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    } else {
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

if you want to completely disconnect user from facebook login use:

```
 public void disconnectFromFacebook() {

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        return; // already logged out
    }

    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
            .Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        }
    }).executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I am still getting "Continue As XY". It might be because when i click on the LoginButton it logs me in to the Native Facebook App. But when i click on LogOut that doesnt logs me OUT from tha Native Facebook App.

Comment: i'm still not logged out from the native facebook app. And still getting the same user if i click on "Contine with facebook".

Answer (score 0):

To really disconnect from facebook with the android SDk and avoid auto login after you must use

```
    val accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
    val request = GraphRequest.newDeleteObjectRequest(accessToken, "me/permissions", { response ->
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut() //not really needed i think
        })
    request.executeAsync()
```

In response you have a responseCode == 200 if OK

Comment: Gives me `E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}` and still logged in ):